# Trouble generating custom probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I want to generate random distributed numbers from a uniform distribution ($x$ is a uniform distributed number). The probability density that I want to obtain is:

$$
f(y) = \mathcal{N}e^{\beta y}
$$

The $\mathcal{N}$ is a normalization constant that ensures that $\mathcal{N}\int_0^\infty f(y)dy=1$.

For doing it, I have to calculate: $\mathcal{N}\int_0^{y} f(y')dy'=x$, which, upon calculating the inverse function to obtain $y$ I get

$$
y = \frac{1}{\beta}ln(\frac{\beta*x}{\mathcal{N}}+1)
$$

My problem is that when I sample this using numpy, and then plot the histogram for $y$, my histogram has a cut-off around $0.36$. Is it wrong my derivation or is it something that I am missing?

Comment: For instance $\beta=-8.39851811$ and $\mathcal{N}=8.80332017964$

Comment: you need $\int f =1$ - that is $N=-\beta>0$ and $y=\frac 1\beta\log(1-x)$.

Comment: But the integral is $\frac{\mathcal{N}}{\beta}(e^{\beta y}-1)=x$, so I have a prefactor in $x$, this $\beta/\mathcal{N}
$

Comment: Where does $\mathcal{N}\int_0^{y} f(y')dy'=x$ even come from?

Comment: Because I want to generate random numbers with density $f(y)$ from a uniform distribution, where $x$ is a random variable uniformly distributed.

Comment: Yes, you explained it alright. You didn't explain what that equality means and where it comes from.

Comment: For example, Section III: https://www.unf.edu/~cwinton/html/cop4300/s09/class.notes/Distributions1.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34737/discussion-between-user2820579-and-a-s).